# Why do network cards without all of the wires work?

Tags: ethernet, network-adapter

I recently acquired an older model of PC, and the network card in it did not work. A friend of mine had a spare laying around for me to use as a replacement, but I noticed that it only had 4 of the 8 pins to connect to the cable. He said this wasn't a problem and that it would work, but couldn't explain why (the non-functional one that came with the PC had all 8). I tested it out, and sure enough, it works. How can it work if it only has 4 of the 8 connectors?

**UPDATE/EDIT**:
Wikipedia states:

```
Conductors required
10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX Ethernet connections require two cable pairs. 
1000BASE-T Ethernet connections require four cable pairs.
```

Does it matter which two cable pairs are present? Or can any two pairs be used?

Comment: might want to change the word "connectors" in the question to wires.

Comment: For an answer to your edit, 4, 5 7, 8 are the pins for half duplex, you can look up Ethernet over twisted pair on Wikipedia. I would link it but I'm on my cell phone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For 10 and 100 base T cable, only 2 pairs of wires are used.  Some cable manufacturers save money by not including all the wires.  1000 base T requires all 4 pairs of wires.

Take a look at a standard land based telephone cord.  Some have 2 wires, some have 4.  Only 2 wires are needed to function, the other 2 are for a second phone line.

Check out the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) entry on Category 5 cabling for more detail.

To answer your modified question, yes, the pairs do matter.  Look at this [article](http://www.securitycameraworld.com/technical-Articles/Cat5-RJ45-Colors-and-Wiring-Guide-Diagram.asp).  The transimt (tx) and receive (rx) wires are noted in the diagram.

Comment: +1 Thank you, very helpful. However, it raised another question which the Wikipedia article did not answer. Question has been edited.

Comment: yes, i amended the answer.